# Change value of guice instance on runtime

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, guice

I´m using google guice to inject this class example

```
 class A {
     String a;
 }
```

Then is injected in my class B

```
  class B {
     @Inject A aInstance;

     public void checkValue(){
            System.out.println(aInstance.a);
     }   
  }
```

Maybe using aspectJ, but what I would like is, that one test of mine, would get this A instance and would set the "a" string as "foo", before execute the test that cover the B class, so when the B class invoke checkValue this one would print "foo"

Comment: If you get the same instanceof `A` that should work. I don't know guice that well but I'd guess it has some sort of scoping like CDI, i.e. it probably is able to inject the same instance of a class into multiple injection targets.

Comment: It sounds like a task for mocking framework. See Mockito: http://mockito.org/

Answer (score 1):

You mention the word *test* in your question - if you are writing a **jUnit test** for B you could perform the injection in an @Before clause, as demonstrated [here](http://www.journaldev.com/2403/google-guice-dependency-injection-example-tutorial).

```
private Injector injector;

@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
    injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(A.class).to(MockedInstanceOfAWithValueFoo.class);
        }
    });
}
```

You could also call

```
bind(A.class).toInstance(new MockedInstanceOfAWithValueFoo());
```

If we assume that A has a constructor by which we can define A.a, the mocked instance could look like this:

```
public class MockedInstanceOfAWithValueFoo extends A{

    public MockedInstanceOfAWithValueFoo() {
        super("foo");
    }

}
```

Again, you could make your mocked class accept the value of A.a through a constructor to make the creation of B (and the associated value of A.a) more dynamic.

Comment: This code is not compiling. At least with a mock class that I created

Comment: What part is not compiling? The class 'MockedInstanceOfAWithValueFoo' does not exist. You need to create this yourself. Since A is not an interface, I imagine that the mocked instance will simply be a class that extends A, and which perhaps sets the A.a field through a setter or a constructor.

Comment: yes of course, I create my own mock class. But you´re right I forgot make the mock extends A. Thanks

Comment: Anyway it´s not gonna be so simple since is not a Unit test but a BDD test

Answer (score 1):

With Mockito:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class MyTest {

    @Mock
    A mockA;

    @InjectMocks
    B mockB;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockA.a = "Foo";
        //when(mockA.getA()).thenReturn("Foo"); //if you use getter
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        assertNotNull(mockA);
        assertNotNull(mockA.a);
        assertNotNull(mockB);
        assertNotNull(mockB.ainstance);
        mockB.checkValue();
    }

}
```